# Atomic models in the 1910's and early 1920's

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, atomic-theory

The Rutherford model that invalidated the plum pudding model occured in 1909, while the first model for quantum mechanics was around 1924, leaving a period of 15 years without an adequate model for the atom, as the Rutherford planetary model did not work out due to the emission of radiations. That period of history for the atomic model is usually skipped in most history of science texts. What models did exist back then to explain the atomic structure? I vaguely recall something about ring-like electrons, but that's about it.

Comment: ;D I also asked the same.

Comment: @user36790: Except you noted the Bohr, quantized model, which this question does not.

Comment: I don't think there was any other model during that time. They just had the planetary model, and they didn't know how to fix its deficiencies.